# Where do I start with Django when I have a development server running and have a GET request from API?

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, query-string

I'm running a Django development server instance and working with the LinkedIn API.

Right now, I have a python script that I can run that will open a new tab in the default web browser and ask the user to sign in with their LinkedIn account, much like a web app would open a popup window to ask for your credentials.

The python script has the Django dev server instance as the redirect URI, so the following message comes up when I authenticate:

```
[19/Jul/2013 08:24:33] "GET /?code=xxxxxxxxx&state=xxxxxxxxxxxxx HTTP/1.1" 200 1954
```

Right now, I have to manually copy the code into command line before receiving the proper OAuth access token to make API calls.

I want to make the authentication process automated and in a Django app to integrate with the front end I'll be building. I've read through django.http docs and I'm pretty sure I need to start by making a new app and using that in the `views.py` file of the app.

How do I extract the query using Django (or Python if I can still integrate this into the app) and use it properly?

Answer (score 0):

You can read the parameters of the url with the Request object you have access to in your views.py.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/

```
def my_view(request):
  code = request.GET.get('code')
  state = request.GET.get('state')
  # do something
```